# How to read data from cin and send on socket while async_accepting from that socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I currently have a server using Asio like the example [here](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.4.8/src/examples/local/stream_server.cpp). Currently, it works as intended in that every packet it receives from the client is responded to by the `session::handle_read` function.

However, I want to modify the server so that it can also accept data from the command line and send that across the packet to the client (unsolicited by the client) while still listening for input from the client.

I'm not really sure where to start modifying what I have... so pointers there would be helpful. I'm thinking that I need additional work in the `session::start` function (e.g. read from the command line then use an `async_write` to write out that data); does that seem logical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to modify the server so that it
>   can also accept data from the command
>   line and send that across the packet
>   to the client

Use a `posix::stream_descriptor` to read from `STDIN_FILENO`. See this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210796/283302) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210796/boost-asio-how-to-write-console-server/5211349#5211349) for a more complete example and solution.