# Reading asynchronously from stdin with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, qt4, stdin

I would like to read asynchronously from stdin with Qt. I don't want to use a separate thread or have to setup a timer to periodically check if the file descriptor has data. How can I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with using a thread or polling?

Comment: Don't want to waste resources on the extra thread and have to deal with locking not if I can avoid it. I also don't want to waste cpu cycles when my app is idle.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to optimize your code before seeing whether or not it actually needs to be. I'd say the thread approach is probably too complex, but polling periodically with a timer is pretty dang cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the Qt documentation, it says you cannot do this because it is not portable. Why not use a TCP socket that should work assuming you have control over the other end. Worst case you can make a proxy application.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to integrate stdin/stdout/stderr I/O with the QT event loop, you can either:

1. Use a [QSocketNotifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html) and do the I/O yourself with `read(2)` and `write(2)`, or
2. Get a  [`QFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) object and call [`bool QFile::open ( int fd, OpenMode mode )`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) to do Qt-style I/O with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using boost, you could use the Asio library. A [`posix::stream_descriptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html) assigned to `STDIN_FILENO` works quite well. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211349/283302).

Answer (score 2):

Try using QSocketNotifier

```
QSocketNotifier * notifier = new QSocketNotifier( FDSTDIN, QSocketNotifier::Read );
connect(notifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(readStdin(int)));
```

Comment: I didn't try it, found this solution somwhere

Comment: It does actually work.... on Linux. Simplified your testcase to use Qt5 syntax: http://www.kdab.com/~dfaure/2019/stdin_socketnotifier.cpp

Comment: For Windows, one needs to use QWinEventNotifier, as done here https://github.com/juangburgos/QConsoleListener/blob/master/src/qconsolelistener.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works for you:

https://github.com/juangburgos/QConsoleListener

Works like this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QConsoleListener>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // listen to console input
    QConsoleListener console;
    QObject::connect(&console, &QConsoleListener::newLine, &a, [&a](const QString &strNewLine) {
        qDebug() << "Echo :" << strNewLine;
        // quit
        if (strNewLine.compare("q", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0)
        {
            qDebug() << "Goodbye";
            a.quit();
        }
    });

    qDebug() << "Listening to console input:";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Chris pointed out the best way would be to have a separate thread that would poll from the `stdin` and populate data for the display or processing thread to process.

Now you can certainly set up `QTimer` and set up a handler for the `timeout()` signal to read from `stdin` as well.  The method of implementing is entirely up to you.

And for the second method you can take a look at [QT's timer class documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html) for an example on how to do this.  One thing to remember would be to actually restart the timer once your processing is completed.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea until you look at the impact on battery life for mobiles and laptops. Not to mention you introduce an artificial latency that makes your application seem sluggish.

Comment: @ericdescourtis Given this answer is over 5 years old there are much better options now.

Comment: ‮?degnahc sah yltcaxe tahw ot sa su nethgilne uoy dluoC !taerG